# Tweaking Mac OS X full-screen console mode

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout, console, tty

When using the full-screen console mode in Mac OS X accessed by entering the username '>console', I would like to use a different keyboard layout and would like support for colors.

The terminal seems to be set to vt100 while Terminal windows use xterm-color, but I can't figure out how to change that (if that is even the way to enable color).

I also grep'd for loadkeys under /etc to try to determine where the keyboard layout was being loaded, but came up with nothing.

Comment: Earn a bounty for answering the keyboard layout part of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your keyboard layout you might find you'd have to manually remap keys; sadly I'm only familiar with doing this for an X11 manager.  Perhaps that notion will set you in the right direction.

For your coloring needs, type this in:

> export TERM=xterm-color

It will switch your term to xterm-color like Terminal, then try `ls -G` (color mode for `ls`).

Comment: Setting the TERM worked and setting it in my .bash_profile made it permanent.

I tried kbdcontrol to remap the keys but it doesn't seem to be available.

Answer (score 0):

@Evan, does [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4099?viewlocale=en_US) solve your bounty?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It does change the keyboard layout for the login window, but the `>console` terminal remains in qwerty.

Comment: damn.  well it was worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

From [How to change the language displayed in the login window](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4102) :

The text of the login window will be displayed in the language that was selected when Mac OS X was installed, or the language selected the first time Mac OS X was started on a new Mac. Learn how you can change the language used for the login window.
Products Affected

There are two ways to change the language of the login window:

- Reinstall Mac OS X and select the desired language during installation, or
- Use the steps below depending on your version of Mac OS X.

**Mac OS X v10.4 or later**

1. Login as a user who has an administrator account.
2. Open Terminal (in /Applications/Utilities/).
3. Type or paste this command in Terminal:
   `sudo languagesetup`
   and press Return.
4. When prompted for a password, enter your account password and press Return again.  If your user has no password (a blank password) and you are using Mac OS X 10.5 or later, see [Mac OS X 10.5 or later: sudo command requires a non-blank admin password](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4103).
5. A list of available languages will be displayed.
   Type the number that appears next to the language you want to use, then press Return.
6. Quit Terminal.

Comment: This may work for switching languages but unfortunately doesn't have an option for keyboard layouts like Dvorak.

Comment: Dvorak was not specified in the question, but it is strange that you don't have it. Does it exist in System Preferences ?

Comment: It's possible to change it in System Prefs, but nothing seems to affect the `>console` keyboard layout.